# Upload photo to facebook fanpage appcelerator titanium

Tags: facebook-graph-api, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have an app that lets me take a pic or choose from my gallery and upload it to my personal fb page.

How can I let it upload to my fanpage instead of my own page?

I use this for putting it in my page:

```
var data = {picture: image};
            Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me/photos', data, "POST", function(e){
        if(e.success) {
 var d = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
 title: Titanium.App.Properties.getString("namn"),
 message: 'Uploaded!',
 buttonNames: ['Ok'],
});
d.show();  }
```

It wont just work to change the 'me/photos'  to 'pageid/photos'.

What will I have to do to get it to work?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

As described under the `photos` secion in the Graph API Documentation for
[Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

You should name the parameter `source` and not `picture`

Also, make sure you have the `publish_stream` and `manage_pages` permissions

Comment: What response are you getting from graph api ?

Comment: facebook errdomain 10000.  That should indicate that my permissions is wrong right? i can post comments, likes etc to the page so thats ok but i cant post an image . ihave publish_stream photo_upload permissions  it wont matter if i try to post to the feed instead of photos either.

Comment: Yes but if i set manage_pages permissions isnt it just the pages owned by the user that is logged in that will affect? I want users to be able to upload their photos to my bands facebook page.

Comment: I found something here that seems legit:  http://www.kerstner.at/en/2012/03/post-to-facebook-fanpage-as-page-admin-through-app-via-impersonation/       but i am not sure how to write that for Titanium......